# How to Eager Loading belongs to relationship using GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have these two structs:

```
// `User` belongs to `Company`, `CompanyID` is the foreign key
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

If I want to query User with Company data included in it, I can do this:

```
user := new(User)
db.Preload("Company").Find(user)
```

But I want to query Company and include User in it, If I do this

```
company := new(Company)
db.Preload("User").Find(company)
```

It will throw an error like:

> "User: unsupported relations for schema Company"

That's understandable, because there is no field User in Company struct.

if I add User field like this:

```
type Company struct {
      ID   int
      Name string
      User User
}
```

it throws error like:

> "illegal cycle in declaration of User"

Comment: change the company structure to `type Company struct {
 gorm.Model
 ID   int
 Name string
 User *User
}`  and check

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by @kaushik, a working solution could be:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string
    CompanyID int
    Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    User *User
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Company{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    // db.Create(&Company{ID: 1, Name: "ACME", User: &User{Name: "John"}})
    // db.Create(&User{Model: gorm.Model{ID: 2}, Name: "Suzy", Company: Company{ID: 2, Name: "XYZ"}})
    var company Company
    if err := db.Debug().Model(&Company{}).Preload("User").Find(&company).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("User:", company.User.Name)
}
```

Let me know if this helps you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your answer, but the User and Company struct I have posted are just examples to describe my problem which is belongs to relationship not one-to-many, in fact I got those structs from gorm official docs website which also uses those structs to describe belongs to relationship.

Comment: Oh silly me! I'm gonna adjust my answer ASAP. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

how about we embed Company struct type?

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}

type CompanyBelongsTo struct {
    City
    User User
}

func (c CompanyBelongsTo) TableName() string {
    return "companies"
}
```

then you can eiger load like this:

```
companies := []models.CompanyBelongsTo{}
tx.Preload("Province").Find(&companies)
```